# charging issue iPhone 12 pro refurbished

Tags: battery, iphone, charging, charger

I recently purchased a refurbished iPhone 12 Pro, but I've noticed an issue with the battery charging. When using an official iPhone charger, there's no problem, and the phone charges as it should. However, if I use a non-iPhone cable (which works perfectly fine with other iPhones in the house), a peculiar situation arises depending on the order in which I connect the adapter and cable (clearly, the cable and adapter are always connected):

- If the adapter is already plugged into the wall and I connect the
  cable to the phone, the phone doesn't charge.
- If I connect the cable
  to the phone first and then plug in the adapter to the wall (or
  unplug and plug it back in), the phone charges without issues.

The exact same problem occurs with different adapters and cables as long as they are not original. We have never encountered any issues with other iPhones in the family, even when using the same cables (the other iPhones are 12, not "Pro" if that is helpful).

My concern is this: should I replace the phone, given that I have the option to do so (it's refurbished) at no additional cost? Is it a battery issue (which might deteriorate in the future), or does it use a peculiar recognition system for original cables that is normal in iPhones?

I'm not too worried about the minor inconvenience of unplugging from the wall, but rather about the possibility of damage to the battery or the charging port.

Thank you all for your attention, and happy new year!

Comment: This is off topic here and belongs in Ask Different.